# Let $G$ be a graph and $H$ a subgraph of G with $V (H) = V (G)$. Prove that if $H$ is connected then so is $G$

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness

Having trouble with this proof. Here is my attempt so far.

Let G be a graph s.t. $G = (V, E, h)$. Let H be a connected subgraph of G s.t. $V(H) = V(G)$.

Since $V(H) = V(G)$, for every $ v \in V(G)$ there exists a $v \in V(H)$ and vice versa

$\implies$ $H = G - S$, where $S = \{e \in E(G) \mid e \notin E(H)\}$

I feel like I am on the right track here but I am stuck on how to show that if G must be connected now. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

To show that a graph is connected, you need to pick two arbitrary vertices in its vertex set, and show that there is a path between them. What can you say about $v_1, v_2\in V(G)=V(H)$, assuming that $H$ is connected?

Comment: You can say there exists a path from $v_{1} \rightarrow v_{2}$    $\forall v_{1}, v_{2} \in V(H)$. How do I translate that to G though?

Comment: That path involves elements of $E(H)$ and $V(H)$, which are subsets of $E(G)$ and $V(G)$, respectively.

Comment: Thank you! Don't know how I missed that!